# How can i build a modular program with angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, modular

for a custumer i build a program which show contracts and a detail for a chosen contract for a lot of facilities. In the detail you can add and edit the data.
Now the customer want see looseparts to on the same way.
But not all locations of my customer want see the same. 
So i want build my program modular.

[image]

The program must recognize that a module is missing, and omit this in accordance with.

Anywhere here can give me tips for this?
Thanks a lot.